# Calculating width from percent to pixel then minus by pixel in LESS CSS

Tags: css, less, pixel

I will calculate width in some element from percent to pixel so I will minus -10px via using **LESS** and **calc()**. It´s possible?

```
div {
    span {
        width:calc(100% - 10px);
    }
}
```

I using CSS3 `calc()` so it doesn't work: `calc(100% - 10px)`

> **Example:** if 100% = 500px so width = 490px (500-10);

I made a demo for testing : http://jsfiddle.net/4DujZ/55/

so padding will say: **5** (10px / 2) all the time when I resizing.

Can I do it in **LESS**? I know how to do in jQuery and simple CSS like margin padding or else...  but i will try to do functional in **LESS** with `calc()`

Comment: As a general rule, [don't style selectors that have no semantics](http://smacss.com/book/type-module#avoid), like `div` or `span`.

Comment: Here's a cross browser mixin I wrote for using calc on any css property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24790931/916734

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You can escape the `calc` arguments in order to prevent them from being evaluated on compilation.

Using your example, you would simply surround the arguments, like this:

```
calc(~'100% - 10px')
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/c5aq20b6/

---

I find that I use this in one of the following three ways:

### Basic Escaping

Everything inside the `calc` arguments is defined as a string, and is totally static until it's evaluated by the client:

#### LESS Input

```less
div {
    > span {
        width: calc(~'100% - 10px');
    }
}
```

#### CSS Output

```
div > span {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

### Interpolation of Variables

You can insert a LESS variable into the string:

#### LESS Input

```less
div {
    > span {
        @pad: 10px;
        width: calc(~'100% - @{pad}');
    }
}
```

#### CSS Output

```
div > span {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

### Mixing Escaped and Compiled Values

You may want to escape a percentage value, but go ahead and evaluate something on compilation:

#### LESS Input

```less
@btnWidth: 40px;
div {
    > span {
        @pad: 10px;
        width: calc(~'(100% - @{pad})' - (@btnWidth * 2));
    }
}
```

#### CSS Output

```
div > span {
  width: calc((100% - 10px) - 80px);
}
```

Source: http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-escape.

Comment: You rock, dude! Thank you for those examples and explanations. Do you happen to know how I could divide an unkown width of a container (let's call it div.categories) into 4 equal parts, using LESS?

Comment: @ShawnSpencer: In between the lines, there's a lot of obscurity. Can you create a JSFiddle illustrating what you're trying to solve? I can try to guess the use case, but I'm inhibited by not knowing the full details, and I'm sure you know how that goes—your worst inhibitions tend to psych you out in the end.

Comment: I'm not inclined to resign to maturity. Since I'm going for a straightforward CSS solution, and since I was able to make things work, using one of the answers, I'm good for now. Thank you for offering to look at a JSFiddle example though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think `width: -moz-calc(25% - 1em);` is what you are looking for.
And you may want to give this [Link](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/) a look for any further assistance

Answer (score -3):

Or, you could use the margin attribute like this:

```
    {
    background:#222;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: OP wants the width 10px less than 100% width. Your CSS does not do that. It will make it *wider* than 100%.

Answer (score -3):

Try this :

```
width:auto;
margin-right:50px;
```