# Calculate % of vw in pixels, divide by 2 and add pixels to the result

Tags: css, less

the title pretty much explains it all, I have this calculation in LESS, it is the left inset of my sideBar.

**sidebar**: 300px

**content**: 960px

```
// half of the empty space
left: calc(~'(100% - 1260px)' / 2)
```

Then to calculate the inset of my content div, i need to repeat this and add the width of my sidebar.

**I have tried**

```
// half of the empty space
left: calc(~'(100% - 1260px)' / 2 +300px)

// half of the empty space
left: calc((~'(100% - 1260px)' / 2)+300px)
```

I've also tried to put the original calculatin into a variable and add 300px to that, no luck.

**So is this even possible?**

Comment: You may want to have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206484/why-is-this-less-expression-a-syntax-error-depending-on-the-math-operation/36214895#36214895. Put the entire math within the quotes that follow the escape operator. The reasons for this is explained in that answer.

Comment: In both cases the mistake is in escaping only the part of the `calc` expression - the proper escaping would be `calc(~'(100% - 1260px) / 2')` and `calc((~'(100% - 1260px) / 2 + 300px')` (the former one compiles w/o a error somewhat accidentally as a side-effect as described in the A linked by @Harry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the escape characters inside of the parentheses to get that part of the statement to evaluate before LESS kicks in:
`left: calc(~'(100% - 1260px) / 2')`

I found a great explanation of how this works for you here: 
[Calculating width from percent to pixel then minus by pixel in LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814616/calculating-width-from-percent-to-pixel-then-minus-by-pixel-in-less-css?rq=1)