# The curious case of calc(25% - 1px) that equals 24%

Tags: css, less

I've recently run into this very interesting bug(?) where my css includes:

```
width: calc(25% - 1px);
```

And the computed css shows:

```
width: calc(24%);
```

This was the case in

Firefox(Version 44.0.2),

Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.112 m),

and IE11 (Version 11.0.9600.18205)

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

**EDIT:** same thing happens with `calc(25% - 1em)` and `calc(25% - 1rem)`

**EDIT 2:** here's an example https://codepen.io/martindoychinov/pen/wGYxOO

**EDIT 3:** apparently it is because im using LESS

Comment: two questions here ?  what is the size of the original container and what happens when you use em or rem instead of px

Comment: And you'd need to demo.

Comment: As @Paulie_D said. Try to put a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I just added my example and the exact same problem occurs! Your example shows correctly though, where am I going wrong? **EDIT:** just updated, apparently its because im using LESS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using LESS as your CSS pre-processor in your example.

You need to escape the expression

```
width: calc(~'25% - 1px');
```

- Seen at [Calculating width from percent to pixel then minus by pixel in LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814616/calculating-width-from-percent-to-pixel-then-minus-by-pixel-in-less-css))
- Also this answer may help you for *cross browser mixing* [Disable LESS-CSS Overwriting calc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc/24790931#24790931)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!